# TI C55: DMA to SPI Interface?

Tags: dma, texas-instruments, tms

Is it possible to use DMA with the SPI interface on TMS320C55xx DSPs? I see that the DMA controller has events for I2C, I2S, UART, MMC, SD, and internal and external memory, but SPI seems a curious omission; likewise SPI is not listed in the memory map for the DMA controllers.